# Getting GPS/Network locations in two threads simultaneously in android

Tags: android

For some reasons(don't ask why (: ) I need to determine a GPS/Network locations in a two threads simultaneously. Will it work fine with a LocationManeger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use single Location Listener and provide location data to your threads from that listener